Openapi javascript SDK generator client API access
I've been trying to setup a small "fullstack app" to try out the openapi SDK generator. I tried keeping everything as simple as possible but I'm still running in to issues.
Project structure:

On the server side I'm using express to setup i single /hi endpoint. like this
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.get("/hi", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "hi from the server" });
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("server running on port 3000");
})

My openAPI spec file looks as follows:
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: api
  description: This serves as a base for other REST API's
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /hi:
    get:
      description: Say hi to the server
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Succes
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string

The file seems to work correctly as I can easily generate an SDK running the npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i ../api/docs/index.yaml -g javascript -o src/api from the client directory.
On the client side I just use basic HTML, CSS and JS to tryout the SDK.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>

    </main>

    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

import { DefaultApi } from './api/src/index.js';

const api = new DefaultApi('http://localhost:3000');

const testConnection = async () => {
    console.log("testing connection...")
    const response = await api.hiGet()

    const data = await response.json()

    console.log(data)
}

testConnection()

But when I startup a live server from my HTML page I Get the following errors:


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
